# How to Close Mean menu bookmark links

Tags: mobile, menu, onclick

I have a mobile menu and I have a bookmark within the same same page.  I need to be able to have the menu close when clicking on the bookmark:

```
<li><a href="#whyfrightkits">Why FrightKits</a></li>
```

Since the page does not refresh the menu does not close.

I tried a few options but nothing has worked.  Can someone please give me direction or a solution to how I can resolve this?  Here's the url of the site I am working on. https://www.falconcropprotection.com/index.asp

The bookmark link is WhyFrightKits.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem;

```
<li><a href="#whyfrightkits" class="hidden-xs">Why FrightKits</a></li>
<li><a href="#whyfrightkits" class="visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Why FrightKits</a></li>
```

Comment: That did not work. I script I am using is jquery.meanmneu.js. I am not savvy when it comes to javascript but I did notice this:  onePage: false .   I changed that to 'true' and now it works as expected.

Thanks for you help anyway.